# Snowflake null java.lang.NullPointerException ERROR when launching Java UDF

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, snowpark

I created a Java UDF in a snowflake in order to query GeoIp2 library and get the ISO code of a column list of IP. I have '@AWS_CSV_STAGE/lib/geoip2-2.8.0.jar','@AWS_CSV_STAGE/geodata/GeoLite2-City.mmdb' and 'maxmind-db-1.2.1.jar' already staged so i included their location with full URL from the AWS_CSV_STAGE in the import option, so i can use the GeoLite2 library and querying the database and get the ISO code (US, NL) for each IP provided. When i save the function it's correctly saved, but when i launch the SELECT on my table i get the error:

```
User Error Report: Java Stack Trace: java.lang.NullPointerException at function_handler_0//MyUDFHandler.isoCode(InlineCode.java:18) in function GEOLOCATOR with handler MyUDFHandler.isoCode
```

i have a doubt about the following lines of code if they are really using the database:

```
URL resource = MyUDFHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResource("GeoLite2-City.mmdb");
File file = new File(resource.toURI());
DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(file).build();
```

code:

```
create or replace function DB_TEST.MAIN_SCHEMA.GEOLOCATOR(IP VARCHAR)
  returns string not null
  language java
  imports=('@DB_TEST.MAIN_SCHEMA.AWS_CSV_STAGE/geodata/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', '@DB_TEST.MAIN_SCHEMA.AWS_CSV_STAGE/lib/maxmind-db-1.2.1.jar', '@DB_TEST.MAIN_SCHEMA.AWS_CSV_STAGE/lib/geoip2-2.8.0.jar')
  handler='MyUDFHandler.isoCode'
as
$$
import com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.exception.GeoIp2Exception;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.model.CityResponse;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.record.Country;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


class MyUDFHandler {
    public static String isoCode (String ip_address) throws Exception {
        URL resource = MyUDFHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResource("GeoLite2-City.mmdb");
        File file = new File(resource.toURI());
        DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(file).build();
        CityResponse response = reader.city(InetAddress.getByName(ip_address));
        return response.getCountry().getIsoCode();
    }
}
 
$$;

SELECT IP, GEOLOCATOR(IP) as GEO_IP FROM DANGEROUS_IPS LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you for sharing the codes. It helped me to repro the issue. As I see, there are 2 problems here. One is how you access the mmdb (database file), and the second one (*occurs when the first one is solved*) is missing imports.

Instead of using "getResource" and "toURI", I used System.getProperty("com.snowflake.import_directory") to get the directory path (and build the file path).

Then I also added missing jackson-* JAR files.

Here is the script:

```
create or replace function  GEOLOCATOR(IP VARCHAR)
  returns string not null
  language java
  imports=('@MYSTAGE/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', '@MYSTAGE/maxmind-db-1.2.1.jar', '@MYSTAGE/geoip2-2.8.0.jar', '@MYSTAGE/jackson-core-2.14.1.jar'
          , '@MYSTAGE/jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar', '@MYSTAGE/jackson-annotations-2.14.1.jar')
  handler='MyUDFHandler.isoCode'
as
$$
import com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.exception.GeoIp2Exception;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.model.CityResponse;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.record.Country;

    
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


class MyUDFHandler {
    public static String isoCode (String ip_address) throws Exception {
        String importDirectory = System.getProperty("com.snowflake.import_directory");
        String fPath = importDirectory + "GeoLite2-City.mmdb";
        File file = new File( fPath ) ;
        DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(file).build();
        CityResponse response = reader.city(InetAddress.getByName(ip_address));
        return response.getCountry().getIsoCode();
    }
}
 
$$;
   
SELECT IP, GEOLOCATOR(IP) as GEO_IP FROM VALUES('62.45.42.100') tmp(IP) ;

+--------------+--------+
|      IP      | GEO_IP |
+--------------+--------+
| 62.45.42.100 | NL     |
+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you, everything worked!

Comment: Great answer - now, you could get better performance at scale with lazy initialization (just parse the `mmdb` once): https://hoffa.medium.com/free-ip-address-geolocation-with-maxmind-and-snowflake-676e74ea80b8